# MPI_Gather Dynamic 2D Allocated Arrays - MPI C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

On each processor I have dynamically allocated *2D arrays* as:

```
char** result = malloc(maxRows * sizeof(char*));
int i;
for(i = 0 ; i<maxRows; ++i) result[i] = malloc(maxCols * sizeof(char));
```

But these arrays are filled with different sizes stored in variable called `count` *where `count < maxRows`*.
I want to collect these arrays to one single array at the master.
Any ideas please?

Example of data:

```
Process 1 : count = 3 , result[0] = "hello" , result[1] = "MPI" , result[2] = "World".
Process 2 : count = 2 , result[0] = "hi" , result[1] = "stackoverflow".
```

I wish master process returns:

```
Process 0 (master) : count = 5 , result[0] = "hello" , result[1] = "MPI" ,
result[2] = "World" , result[3] = "hi" , result[4] = "stackoverflow".
```

Comment: For starters, you should probably allocate your 2D array as a contiguous block of memory. This is both more efficient resources-wise and will help you treat your 2D array as a 1D array

Comment: You **have to** allocate your 2D array in contiguous memory. Then ranks do not have the same `count`, you need to use `MPI_Gatherv()` to gather the strings (and unless the root rank is aware of all the `count` of all the ranks, you have to `MPI_Gather()` the `count` before that). If you are still stuck, share your efforts and upload a [MCVE].